# How to create an animation like Refleclty app in Jetpack Compose? Scrollable Row Color Selection Y-Offset/Y-Translation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, translate-animation, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I was trying to create something like this[image]

I am facing the problem when calculate Yoffset.
Can anyone please help me with this?

I tried calculating yOffset/translateY for each items but couldn't get the result.
I was able to scale center items, on selction as well.
But for yOffset, couldn't achieve the desired result.